# Newman: How to send ssl cert in newman request

Tags: ssl, curl, postman, newman

I have a curl command that I'd like to have run as a collection using newman:

```
curl -i -v \
 -H "X-FromAppId: APPLICATION" \
 -H "X-TransactionId: 22222222" \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --cacert iis_cert_2018_07.pem \
 --key iis_cert_2018_07.pem \
 --cert iis_cert_2018_07.pem \
 -X GET https://iis-udev02.dev.test.com:8443/iis/v1/common/policies/343
 --insecure
```

I have a collection that executes that GET request, and it works just fine on Postman (after configuring the certs in the UI), but how do I notify newman of those certs when running the collection through the commandline?

I've tried:

```
newman run GETRequest.postman_collection.json  --ssl-client-cert iis_cert_2018_07.pem --ssl-client-passphrase iis_cert_2018_07.pem --insecure
```

But that doesn't work.

How is a cert sent in a newman request?

Comment: Could you also add the error messages from the run, if any?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing in the key as the passphrase here: `--ssl-client-passphrase iis_cert_2018_07.pem`, it should be `--ssl-client-key iis_cert_2018_07.pem`

Try:

```
 newman run GETRequest.postman_collection.json  --ssl-client-cert iis_cert_2018_07.pem --ssl-client-key iis_cert_2018_07.pem --insecure
```

This should work assuming the key is not encrypted with a passphrase, and everything else is right.

The relevant newman documentation is here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#ssl-client-certificates

Answer (score 1):

if you have the key encrypted then you can use the below command

> newman run GETRequest.postman_collection.json --ssl-client-cert iis_cert_2018_07.pem --ssl-client-key iis_cert_2018_07key.pem --ssl-client-passphrase password

Comment: Nice post. Please always use the code icon to format the answer properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PFX certificate, using `--ssl-client-cert` won't work.

Instead you need to use [`--ssl-client-cert-list`](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/tree/develop#using-ssl-client-certificates-configuration-file-supports-multiple-certificates-per-run) to provide a JSON configuration, similar to how you would set it up in Postman.

Save something like the below as `ssl-client-cert.json`:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "xxx",
        "matches": ["https://yyy.com/*"],
        "pfx": {"src": "certifcate.pfx"},
        "passphrase": "mycertpassword"
    }
]
```

And then run `newman`:

```bash
newman run "xxx" --ssl-client-cert-list "ssl-client-cert.json"
```